# Module pkcs#11 from Python

Tags: python, pkcs#11, keyerror

I'm trying to use pkcs11 from Python and I have a problem. I had view many examples and all of them start with the same code. However, when I execute it, console raises error in the third line of the code.

Code:

```
import pkcs11
import os
# Initialise our PKCS#11 library
lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
token = lib.get_token(token_label='DEMO')
```

Error in the line:

```
lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PKCS11_MODULE'
```

Comment: The Python module doesn't implement PKSC#11 itself. It is just a Python wrapper for a module that does the real work. It looks like you haven't installed that. Look at https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pkcs11 wraps a native library. It expects to find that library in a path given by the `PKCS11_MODULE` environment variable.

You should set that environment variable to where you have installed the native component.

```
$ export PKCS11_MODULE='/some/path'
$ python myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this you have to add the route of your driver (in windows a file .dll in linux a file .so), like this:

```
import pkcs11


lib = pkcs11.lib("C:/Windows/System32/eps2003csp11.dll")

for slot in lib.get_slots():
    token = slot.get_token()
    print(token)

    if token.label == '...':
        break
```

In my case, i work with usb token. With this the result is the username of the token connected.